# Including code in shared project only works when x64 platform is selected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS2015 solution with a folder structure like the following:

```
solution
    project1
        (code and headers for project1)
    project2
        (code and headers for project2)
    shared_items_project
        folder1
            (some shared code and headers)
        folder2
            (more shared code and headers)
```

When the target platform is set to x64 code in project1 and project2, which reference the shared project, can include headers in it like `#include "folder1\some_header.h"`. This seems to be the correct behaviour IMO: everything in the shared project appears to lie in the same directory as the project referencing it.
However, switching platform to Win32 stops this working: VS claims it can't find any of the files unless the includes are rewritten like `#include "..\shared_project\folder1\some_header.h"`, implying that the shared project isn't being referenced.

I've been unable to find anything in the project properties that would stop shared items being imported, nor do the project files give any indication that shared item importing is dependent on architecture setting. So I'm at a loss as to why this should be happening - ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding project references in VS++ projects does not affect include paths.

You should manually add referenced project directories into include path for all configurations and platforms.

Comment: This does fix the issue, but I'm still curious why the files were found when targeting x64 but not x86.  
Additionally, [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/) seems to suggest that shared items are automatically accessible without having to modify include paths.

Comment: That link it about C#/.NET, not Native C++.

Comment: It seems surprising that an IDE feature is not universal to all languages supported by the IDE, but fair enough.

Comment: I agree this is how it works -- but it seems to be a bug: From the section "Share source code across multiple C++ projects" on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/30/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/) msdn blog post:  _the files in the referenced “shared items” project will simply be treated as if they were part of the referencing project_.